# MySQL SQL - SET IF with two conditions vor one variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this mysql SQL import, yet it's ignoring the OR @date = '0000-00-00' part. How to set the correct values if I have two conditions for one import field?

SQL:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/html/data.csv' INTO TABLE data_upload (name, status, @date) SET date = IF(@date = '' OR @date = '0000-00-00', NULL, @date);
```

Error:

```
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'date' at row 218739
```

Comment: The problem is not the 2 conditions. The problem is that `0000-00-00` is not a valid date

Comment: ...  unfortunately some values of this column in the csv I received are in 0000-00-00. And when uploading it into the table I want to transform it to NULL. How can I do this?

Comment: 0000-01-01 surely? There is no "0th of nonuary", though I've occasionally mused that this must be the 30th of November. If it's a "date" of 0000-00-00 then it must be a varchar

Comment: ... I understand ... but in the csv file I received ... some values have this format. How can I change it when uploading it?

Comment: you can wrap the variable `@date` like this - `IFNULL(@date,'0000-00-00')`

Comment: thanks @UnknownUser. Could you provide your suggestion as answer and the whole query?

Comment: @PhilippM Is it working? Then only i can post the answer, otherwise that will be misleading for other people. 
`SET date = IF(@date = '' OR @date = '0000-00-00', NULL, @date);`
Replace with 
`SET date = CASE WHEN IFNULL(@date , '0000-00-00') = '0000-00-00' THEN NULL,
   WHEN IFNULL(@date , '0000-00-00') = '' THEN NULL,
   ELSE @date
   END;`

Comment: ... unfortunately no ... I'm getting this error: ERROR 1064 (42000): ' WHEN IFNULL(@date , '0000-00-00') = '' THEN NULL, ELSE @date'